# Unable to install vsftpd on centos 6

Tags: linux, ftp, centos6, yum, vsftpd

I'm having trouble with installing vsftpd on centos 6. When I enter the command

```
yum install vsftpd
```

I get the following:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.widexs.nl
 * extras: mirror.serverbeheren.nl
 * updates: mirror.serverbeheren.nl
Setting up Install Process
No package vsftpd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

And I don't know how to fix this. Does anyone have an idea? Should I add another repo and if so, how should I do this? I'm quite new to centos, I've been used to Ubuntu where I could just use apt-get to install most things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may get better answers from [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Repository

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-6*.rpm
```

Install vsftpd

```
yum install vsftpd
```

Comment: The wget gives a 404 not found.

Comment: CentOS6 is EOL don't expect much! if you are still using CentOS6 then you are dealing with great risk

Answer (score 0):

hmm strange, `yum` is missing some repository where `vsftpd` is located. You still can download it manually:
http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=vsftpd&submit=Search+...&system=centos&arch=

and install it through `rpm` command, or add repository(not sure which one) to your yum