# xdebug, eclipse, centos, remote debugging - unable to stop at breakpoints

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug

dev machine

- mac laptop, 10.8.3
- eclipse, Juno SR2
- php pdt 3.1.2.2012

remote machine

- parallels, vm, CentOS 6.3
- php 5.4.14
- xdebug

/etc/php.ini file

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host="10.211.55.3"
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug_remote_log
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

The PHP files all live on the remote machine and are mapped into a project in eclipse (i.e. i can see the actual files on my dev machine).

I have a debug configuration and can run in the debugger, but can't set or stop at any breakpoint.  I even tried xdebug_break() - just seems to ignore it.

I tried opening port 9000 on the remote machine, no difference.

I tried adding this '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to the eclipse.ini file (found in another post -- had to do with IPv6 vs. IPv4), didn't work.

Project properties in eclipse:

- PHP Debugger: XDebug
- Server:

  - Base URL: h_t_t_p_://10.211.55.3
  - Path Mapping: Path on server: /home/userxyz/workspace/test, Local Path: /test

I am out of ideas about what to try.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not so easy, have some time tomorrow. But first I need information. remote http server. remote FTP server.

Comment: http server: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix), not sure if I have an ftp server...

Comment: We need also an FTP server

Comment: okay, not sure if I have one, but I'm installing one using: sudo yum install vsftp -- dang, not working.  can't find vsftp...  ('No package vsftp available.')

Comment: okay, found out how to get it from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943814/unable-to-install-vsftpd-on-centos-6

Comment: okay, installed vsftp 2.2.2 - same issue.  can run/debug, but won't stop at breakpoints.

Comment: I have told you that is not so easy. I will start an answer continue at 18.00 europe/berlin time.

Comment: look at my started answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I show you Remote server on a windows machine used there filezilla. My Ubuntu 12.04 is at the moment not on.

Try to make a connection to your FTP-server.

Be shure ftp is up and running. Set your ftp server that you can connect from your local machine.

Change your perspective to `Remote System explorer`.
`Remote System explorer` view
Create a new connection

[image]

[image]

Test your ftp connection

[image]

Ftp Server settings.

- 1 For each user to have ftp access, to create a system user.
- 2 If not present the line

> /bin/false

Add to /etc/shells.

- 3 In/etc/passwd file for each FTP user as a login shell /bin/false rejected.

  for example:

> userxy: x: 1003:1002:/home/userxy:/bin/false

Eclipse Ftp setting

[image]

**Final steps.**

only when a connection to ftp server is established.

- On your server create a folder in `/var/www/html` call the folder switch-r .
- Create a new PHP Project call it `Switch-Remote` .

[image]

right click at `Switch-Remote` select new folder.

[image]

after `OK` your project looks

[image]

right click on the new folder switch select `new PHPFile` .

[image]

after `OK` you can see following in eclipse ftp log .

[image]

and your project ..

[image]

open switch.php and replace with new code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252">
<title>Remote Debug</title>
</head>
 <?php
    echo "Hello<br>";
    echo "from DTX-AGIL-3";
    ?>
</html>
```

put a breakpoint at line 8 .

[image]

Create a new Debug Configuration

[image]

Change the settings as seen in the next image .

[image]

Debug with the just created config .
Debug stops at line 8.

[image]

and finish.

[image]

Everything you change or you rename files,
everything is automatically transferred via FTP to the server.

Comment: i am using vsftpd.  the config file is here '/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf', but I don't see any option in there to set the base folder for my user...

Comment: the port should be `21` look here. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/how-to-allow-specific-user-to-login-vsftp-server-446064/

Comment: hm...  still trying to use port 4075, seemingly no matter what property I change.  looked at the link and did what it said there...

Comment: still have the port 4075 - 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused' issue...

Comment: In your browser, Can you really get a connection with `ftp://admin@dtx-agil-3` of course you have to replace with your user name and your ip.

Comment: in a browser (chrome), I can get a connection using: ftp://10.211.55.3 - but it asks for my username/password (pop up dialog) and then it connects just fine and shows me the directory.  however, if in a terminal window, i tried this:

Comment: $ ftp 10.211.55.3:4075
  Connected to 10.211.55.3.
  220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
  331 Please specify the password.
  230 Login successful.
  Remote system type is UNIX.
  Using binary mode to transfer files.
  200 Switching to Binary mode.
  local: 4075 remote: 4075
  229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||27507|).
  550 Failed to open file.
  221 Goodbye.    Got the same thing if I used port 21

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28851/discussion-between-user645402-and-moskito-x)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar configuration here and I am using samba to share the server folder. When I open the project on Eclipse I am using the file the server uses to process the requests. the correct file map is still necessary to break points working as expected.

So, I have a Ubuntu box with the following settings:

Machine Name : `ubuntu-12-10`
Document Root : /www/sites/project1 
Smb share : [www] -> /www

Eclipse Mac OS:
workspace : `/Volumes/ubuntu-12-10/www/sites`
site : `http://ubuntu`
project : project1
maps :

- Path on server : /www/sites/project1
- Local Path : /project1

Adapting for your world you should to be able to stop on breakpoints.