# Netbeans & Eclipse hang when I attempt remote EC2 debugging via Xdebug

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, amazon-ec2, xdebug, remote-debugging

Already, I've checked at least 20 resources and am out of ideas:

I have a clean, remote Ubuntu EC2 instance, fresh from the AMI, having stopped only to install LAMP, phpmyadmin, and xdebug on it. Yes, I have configured my remote EC2 instance's php.ini file as follows:
[image: php.ini]

Meanwhile, back on my laptop I have Netbeans & Eclipse installed. While I can get either to seamlessly upload and Run my php web app on my EC2 site (via SSH/SFTP) as soon as I hit "Debug" from either, index.php gets uploaded, a browser window opens, and then NOTHING HAPPENS. The page doesn't load, the Debug perspective doesn't open, breakpoints don't get triggered, nothing. Netbeans just hangs out saying "waiting for connection" whereas Eclipse just sits at the notorious 57% level (& yes, I toggled the xdebug.idekey before testing with Eclipse)).

So I tested xdebug's functionality on my server according to the instructions found [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/howto_check_xdebug_installationhttps://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/howto_check_xdebug_installation) and [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&tl=en&u=http://ruilima.com/2010/11/ambiente_de_desenvolvimento_php_netbeans_xdebug/) (both passed). I tried changing to port 9001 (in remote php.ini as well as in local Netbeans/Eclipse), I even tried launching this brand spanking-new EC2 instance with pretty much open Security group settings (SSH=0.0.0.0/0), but nothing seems to be working. I am out & out flummoxed, a self-confessed noob, and appreciative of any insight seasoned professionals in the community may have to offer.

Thanks,
Debbie

Comment: maybe my answer here [xdebug-eclipse-centos-remote-debugging-unable-to-stop-at-breakpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180407/xdebug-eclipse-centos-remote-debugging-unable-to-stop-at-breakpoints/16181284#16181284) and here [xdebug-in-linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869189/netbeans-and-xdebug-in-linux/13021858#13021858) . can help you

Comment: Thank-you moskito-x; I will check these out. :) - Debbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a networking issue to me.  Port 9000 may not be accessible. The quickest way to test is to telnet to port 9000 on the remote system (if you have a telnet client installed that allows you to specify which port to telnet to).  If the telnet attempt times out or is closed by the remote system you will see the error and this verifies that there is a networking issue.

I would check /etc/services to make sure that port 9000 is not reserved for use of something else. If port 9000 exists and is uncommented then something else is using the port and that services does not know how to respond to your request so it hangs.

I would do a netstat (lookup params to see "all" listening ports) and make sure the remote system is listening on port 9000.  If you don't see port 9000 then the remote system is not configured to establish the connection.

If you are on a WIFI network then port 9000 may need to be port forwarded to the remote system using the internal cable modem configuration menu/utility.  This is the scenerio I favor because I've wasted so much time solving this kind of problem with different software.

Good luck, you have more troubleshooting ahead of you and different questions to ask to resolve your problem.

Comment: Telnet was working fine, but $ traceroute -T -p 9000 my.tcp.ip.address from the EC2 server back to my laptop showed connectivity failure somewhere after reaching my ISP. Paid a networking specialist $50 to reconfigure my router for me and bam! Now everything works. Thank-you for the Networking tip... that's what I get for neglecting my education in networking.